# Summing numbers separated by commas in string field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, string, summarizing

In QGIS, I have a column separated by comma (shown by column `"lengths"`). I want to sum up elements in it for each row. The column is a text field string.

[image: attribute table]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use arrays in fieldcalculator for this:

```
array_sum(array_foreach(string_to_array("lengths",','),to_real(@element)))
```

1. Turn the string into an array
2. Iterate over the array and convert the string elements to an integer or double
3. Build the sum ([`array_sum()` available since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays))

To catch errors on invalid "numbers", you can use `try()`:

```
array_sum(array_foreach(string_to_array("lengths",','),try(to_real(@element),0)))
```

Comment: I had an error while running it:
Evaluation error in expression "array_sum(array_foreach(string_to_array("lengths",','),to_real(@element)))": Cannot convert '' to double
Execution failed after 0.30 seconds

Comment: That means that at least one of the fields `lengths` is empty. Change the expression to convert such cases to `NULL`, keeping the expression by @MrXsquared otherwiese. Use this expression: `if (lengths is NULL, NULL, array_sum (array_foreach (string_to_array ("lengths",','), to_real (@element))))`