# Calculate sum of comma separated decimal values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, array

The field has decimal values separated by comma and I want to find the sum of those values.

When I run the below code

```
if (
   lengths is NULL, 
   NULL, 
   array_sum (
      array_foreach (string_to_array ("lengths",','), to_real (@element))
   )
)
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert '' to double Execution failed after 0.30 seconds

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: The field 'Lengths' has values like..
5.9,0,3.8
0.68,0.97
etc...
Is this enough

Comment: If this is related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433380/summing-numbers-separated-by-commas-in-string-field-in-qgis you should include the link in your question to provide more context

Comment: Works perfectly for me on simple test data. Have you got a value that's got non-numeric data in it, that isn't NULL? Like a field with just spaces in it?

Comment: I get `Eval Error: Cannot convert ' ' to double` if I try with a field that has a space in it. I'm guessing you've got some non-numeric fields and you need a better test than `lengths is NULL` to match them.

Comment: @Spacedman No, I dont have non_numeric fields. i replaced those with 0. For example initially, I had 5.9,,3.8 I then altered it to 5.9,0,3.8

Comment: Given that it works for me, you need to either supply your data, or test your code with some sample data, or narrow down if your data fails in all cases. Otherwise we're guessing (like I did).

Comment: I can share my data. I tried with sample data and i didn't find issue as it had simple geometry.

Comment: A record with an empty string does not necessarily equate to NULL. You could try adjusting your `if` clause to something like: `if (length("lengths")=0, NULL, array_sum (array_foreach (string_to_array ("lengths",','), to_real (@element))))`

Comment: @Matt Still didn't work. I think previous was code was fine but my dataset still has no values between comma, like 5.03,,6.89. 
I think this is the issue. So I have to alter it to consider '' as 0 when performing array_sum

Comment: That is somewhat confusing, because you previously said you had replaced those instances with 0. See the last line of MrXsquared's answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/433384/128665) (the one that @J.R had already linked to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression calculates the sum of all numbers, even if you have mixed content (characters, `NULL`, empty strings, numbers etc.) in the same field.

It is based on the [`try()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#try) function: everything between two commas is evaluated: if it can be converted, it is changed into a decimal number, in all other cases, a value `0` is created.

`try()` calculates the values if the expression is error-free. In all other cases, it will return `NULL` - or any other value you define in the second argument, here: `0`:

```
array_sum (
    array_foreach (
        string_to_array ("lengths",','), 
        try(to_real (@element),0)
   )
)
```

*The expression takes into consideration just the numbers and ignores everything else:*
[image]

Comment: It didnt work. So I altered the code in the previous step to get 0 in place of ''. Then without try() the initial code worked. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Don't understand: how does your expression look - the one that works? What does not work using `try()`?

Comment: Like I mentioned before, my dataset has field values like, 5,,8    9,6,    ,    I tried using try() but still didn't work. So in the previous step, i altered it so that I get the values like 5,0,8    9,6,0      0,0 and the original code using if() worked fine.

Comment: See updated version, it works with your inputs as well: no need to (manually?) replace `,,` by `,0,`, just use any kind fields as they are

Comment: So Q and A are an exact duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433380/summing-numbers-separated-by-commas-in-string-field-in-qgis and Q just did not read the entire A?

Comment: OK, seems like, I was not aware of that...